# Simpler way to alternate upper and lower case words in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I recently solved this problem, but felt there is a simpler way to do it. I looked into inject, step, and map, but couldn't figure out how to implement them into this code. I want to use fewer lines of code than I am now. I'm new to ruby so if the answer is simple I'd love to add it to my toolbag. Thank you in advance.

**goal:** accept a sentence string as an arg, and return the sentence with words alternating between uppercase and lowercase

```
def alternating_case(str)
    newstr = []
    words = str.split
    words.each.with_index do |word, i|
        if i.even?
            newstr << word.upcase
        else
            newstr << word.downcase
        end
    end
    newstr.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the number of lines in the each_with_index block by using a ternary conditional (true/false ? value_if_true : value_if_false):

```
words.each.with_index do |word, i|
  newstr << i.even? ? word.upcase : word.downcase
end
```

As for a different way altogether, you could iterate over the initial string, letter-by-letter, and then change the method when you hit a space:

```
def alternating_case(str)
  @downcase = true
  new_str = str.map { |letter| set_case(letter)}
end

def set_case(letter)
  @downcase != @downcase if letter == ' '
  return @downcase ? letter.downcase : letter.upcase
end
```

Comment: what does the ? symbol do (thank you for your answer btw) edit: I just visited https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/ and learned something new, thank you sam

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this by using ruby's `Array#cycle`.

`Array#cycle` returns an `Enumerator` object which calls block for each element of enum repeatedly n times or forever if none or nil is given.

```rb
cycle_enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
#=> #<Enumerator: [:upcase, :downcase]:cycle>

5.times.map { cycle_enum.next }
#=> [:upcase, :downcase, :upcase, :downcase, :upcase]
```

Now, using the above we can write it as following:

```rb
word = "dummyword"
cycle_enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
word.chars.map { |c| c.public_send(cycle_enum.next) }.join("")
#=> "DuMmYwOrD"
```

Note: If you are new to ruby, you may not be familiar with `public_send` or `Enumberable` module. You can use the following references.

- [Enumberable#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle)
- [#send & #public_send](https://betterprogramming.pub/metaprogramming-with-ruby-send-and-public-send-methods-f85aa8f91366)

Comment: After defining `cycle_enum`, you could write `word.gsub(/./) { |c| c.public_send(cycle_enum.next) }`.